# Adding picture to docs using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(Ljava/io/InputStream;)[B
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.addPictureData(XWPFDocument.java:1198)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun.addPicture(XWPFRun.java:680)
    at signature.Main.createFile(Main.java:85)
    at signature.Main.listFilesForFolder(Main.java:52)
    at signature.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

when trying to add a picture to docs file using apache POI

The code is as below

```
                XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
                XWPFParagraph par = docx.createParagraph();
                XWPFRun run = par.createRun();
                run.setText(imageUrl);
                File picture = new File("D:\\1.jpg");
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(picture);
                run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "1", 100, 100);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f); 
                docx.write(out); 
                out.close();
```

Comment: what jar are you using?

Comment: Did you try following the advice in the [Apache POI FAQ Entry on this kind of problem](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)? (Hint - you have mis-matched or duplicate jars)

Comment: I am using poi-3.11-beta2 and poi-ooxml-3.11-beta2 jars. Please comment if they are ok or not

Answer (score -1):

It's kinda late but i have found a short tutorial about POI library that may help you adding picts to doc, hope it helps: http://developeriq.in/articles/2012/jul/03/handling-ms-word-documents-using-apache-poi/